# Bash - rsync list of servers

Tags: bash, rsync

I want that a bash script reads a file and execute rsync referring the logindetails of the file.
I have a seperate file with login details to all servers.

I want to use follow format:

```
server=1
type=openvz
ip=1.1.1.1
port=22
user=root
pwd=something
rpath=/home/private/
lpath=s1/

server=2
type=openvz
ip=1.1.1.2
port=22
user=root
pwd=something
rpath=/home/private/
lpath=s2/
```

Please can somebody tell me how can i make a correct loop of the main script to grep all the datas from the logindetails file and make rsync each to other?
example rsync script:

```
source serverlist
sshpass -p $pwd rsync -av --delete $user@$ip:$rpath /home/backup/$lpath
```

I think this must get done via loop, but i dont know how to tell bash to take each server  after another

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want o add another function: If no option is given in shell, then the serverlist should taken from serverlist. But if make (as example) ./aa.sh -r 3 then only item 3 will get used from serverlist.
I know how to use getopts, but how can i modify
    for i in $(seq ${#server[@]}); do
to get called only if no id is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bash indexed arrays to create the configuration file.

```
server[1]=1
type[1]=openvz
ip[1]=1.1.1.1
port[1]=22
user[1]=root
pwd[1]=something
rpath[1]=/home/private/
lpath[1]=s1/

server[2]=2
type[2]=openvz
ip[2]=1.1.1.2
port[2]=22
user[2]=root
pwd[2]=something
rpath[2]=/home/private/
lpath[2]=s2/
```

Then iterate on it.

```
source serverlist

for i in $(seq ${#server[@]}); do
    sshpass -p ${pwd[$i]} rsync -av --delete ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]}:${rpath[$i]} /home/backup/${lpath[$i]}
done
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**

If you want to be able to specify which server to sync on the command line, use the Bash positional parameter `$1`.

```
source serverlist

if [ "$1" ]; then
    sshpass -p ${pwd[$1]} rsync -av --delete ${user[$1]}@${ip[$1]}:${rpath[$1]} /home/backup/${lpath[$1]}

else
    for i in $(seq ${#server[@]}); do
        sshpass -p ${pwd[$i]} rsync -av --delete ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]}:${rpath[$i]} /home/backup/${lpath[$i]}
    done
fi
```

Then, call the script with the optional server number as first argument.

```
./script.sh   # This would sync all servers in the config file. 
./script.sh 2 # This would sync only server number 2.
```

You can use **getopt**, but it is much more complicated.

**Update 2**

If you need to use **getopt**, then convert the **rsync** part of the script into a Bash function.

```
source serverlist

function do_sync() {
    if [ "$1" ]; then
        sshpass -p ${pwd[$1]} rsync -av --delete ${user[$1]}@${ip[$1]}:${rpath[$1]} /home/backup/${lpath[$1]}

    else
        for i in $(seq ${#server[@]}); do
            sshpass -p ${pwd[$i]} rsync -av --delete ${user[$i]}@${ip[$i]}:${rpath[$i]} /home/backup/${lpath[$i]}
        done
    fi
}
```

You can then call this function with the **getopt** option as an argument.

```
do_sync $getopt_option
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what i searched!! Great!

Comment: Hello, i added a comment to my entry post. Maybe you know the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast answer. The problem is, that rsync is only one function and the full script is a little bit longer. So i want to have the code only once.

Comment: @user All rite. See if the `do_sync` function above helps. You just need to pass it the **getopt** option value taken from the command line.

Comment: You must be a bash god. Thanks so much for your help!